# What is a "non multidimensional object property" exactly? (ref: doc of $LISTDATA)

Tags: objectscript

The [documentation of $LISTDATA](http://docs.intersystems.com/latest/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=RCOS_flistdata) says, with regards to the third argument, that:

> The var parameter cannot be a non-multidimensional object property. Attempting to write a value to a non-multidimensional object property results in an  error.

OK, so my understanding is as follows: if you declare, say:

```
Property foo as %String;
```

and then try to:

```
$listdata(whatever, whatever, ..foo)
```

then this is an error. However, if `foo` was declared as:

```
Property foo [ Multidimensional ];
```

then there wouldn't be an error.

Is that it, or is this more subtle? for instance, what if I declare:

```
Property foo as list of %String;
```

would that be multidimensional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Multidimensional](http://docs.intersystems.com/latest/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=ROBJ_property_multidimensional) means that property has the characteristics of a multidimensional array.

`Property foo as list of %String;` would throw an error